# Ruby-on-rails insert/uptade programa externo

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Estou estudando um pouco de Rails para um novo projeto e surgiu uma duvida que é:

Quando dou um `db:migrate`, o Rails cria/altera toda a estrutura do banco de dados – quando necessário – tendo como base o modelo. Pelo que pude ver, o *rake* cria alguns campos de validação e versionamento dos registros.

Minha dúvida é: eu posso ter algum serviço/programa paralelo ao Rails inserindo ou alterando informações do banco de dados que a minha aplicação controla sem prejudicar a integridade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `db:migrate` permite migrar entre **versões da estrutura do banco de dados** e, opcionalmente, fazer *seed* (plantar) alguns dados iniciais. Os **dados incluídos ou alterados**, via rails ou não, não tem uma relação direta com isso, exceto que precisam respeitar a estrutura da tabela.

Embora sua pergunta não seja sobre isso, só pra esclarecer, não é recomendado usar essa rotina para fazer carga de dados entre versões do sistema ([fonte](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data)).

Portanto, não há problemas em haver alterações nos dados na base vindas de serviços externos. A única restrição é que se alguém mudar a estrutura da tabela (via rails ou não), os serviços externos precisam ser atualizados para manter a conformidade. O mesmo é válido para praticamente qualquer tecnologia.